# Angular searchBar directive to change dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a searchBar directive defined here:

```
appControllers.directive('searchBar', [function () {
    return {
        controller: "searchCtrl"
    };
}]);
```

Added to my ionic header bar like this:

```
...
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced  material-background-nav-bar">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <a class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <input type="text" search-bar ng-model="query" ng-change="collectQuery()"></input>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
...
```

This calls `collectQuery()` fine, but doesn't allow me to reference `query`.

```
#search-controller.js
appControllers.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $q) {
...
$scope.collectQuery = function() {
    cancel();
    canceler = $q.defer();
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    console.log($scope.query);

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        search($scope.query);
    }, 300);
};

var search = function(query) {
    $scope.loading = true;

    pendingRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: canceler.promise,
        url: 'https://website.com/api/' + query
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.hits = response.data.contacts;
        window.data = response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).finally(function(){
      $scope.loading = false;
    });

    return pendingRequest;
};
...
```

This always outputs `undefined` to the console and queries the api with `undefined`. If I force it to query the api with 'test' the request returns, but the DOM doesn't change:

```
<ion-view title="Search">
    <ion-content id="mobile-contract-list-content"><!--search results section-->
        <p>{{query}}</p>

        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>

        <md-list class="ng-hide" ng-show="!loading">
            <div class="search-item" ng-repeat="hit in hits">
                <div class="row detail">
                    <i class="fa fa-{{ hit.category }}"></i>

                    <h5>
                        <a href="" target="_blank">{{ hit.search_term }}</a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-list>
    </ion-content><!--end search results section-->
</ion-view>
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm utterly stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that in search controller you haven't defined $scope.query anywhere, so that when `ng-model` updates it sets $scope.query on the nearest available parent scope. If you try taking out the `ng-show` and then try it, most likely the next available scope above `ng-show` is your controller.

If this is the case, this is why people discourage binding ng-model to a primitive value, it should always be bound to an object's property. This is easy to avoid if you use `controllerAs` or `component` because then there's always an associated object to put the property on.

However, if that doesn't work what you can try to do is change `ng-change="collectQuery()"` to `ng-change="collectQuery(query)"` since the change function is always evaluated with the same scope as `ng-model`. At least then you'll be able to narrow it down to whether it's the model not updating properly or a scope issue.

Comment: I accidentally had the 'scope' option in my directive code above. To test i added `{{hits.length}}` to the directive's template, and that shows up fine when I force `collectQuery()` to call the API with 'test'. I assume this is a scope issue, then? If I add the 'scope' option to the return hash, then the directive's ng-change stops calling `collectQuery()`

Comment: Most likely, use the `.scope()` jQlite method to inspect an element's scope and see what results you get when you use it on the input element / directive. If you're using `scope: {}` or `bindings: {}` you might need to call `.isolateScope()` instead.

Comment: That gets me [this](http://i.imgur.com/SijVt65.png) object. That seems contain my `collectQuery()` and `test()` functions from 'searchCtrl' under the '$parent' attribute.

Comment: I added `scope: { ngModel: "=" }` to the return hash, and that got me another similar object, but with the 'searchCtrl' scope showing up in `$parent.$$nextSibling`. When I call `collectQuery('test')` there the DOM updates as expected, so that leads me to believe I'm on the right track using `scope: {}`. I'm just not sure where to go from there, though.

Comment: Using `scope: { ... }` means that you're now using an isolated scope, it doesn't have access to any parent scope's properties. All of the properties you define in that object are related to the directive element not the children. So `scope: { ngModel: '=' }` in  `search controller` means you're trying to bind `<search-bar ng-model="someOuterValue" />`. What you could try is to add `scope: true` and  `$scope.query = { text: '' }` in your search controller instead and then down in your input use `ng-model="query.text"` with `ng-change="collectQuery(query.text)"`.

Comment: Setting `scope: { true }` in the return hash gives me the same problem I have where the input's `ng-change` doesn't fire `collectQuery()`. I'm not sure that it lets the controller access the input's `ng-model` value, either. I added `<p>{{query}}</p>` to the page body, but nothing shows up when I type in the input.

Comment: I simplified my code. Please check the question to see the changes